# Error while using format-number function in xquery

Tags: apache-camel, xquery, saxon

I am using camel-saxon dependency in my project and trying to use format-number function in xquery but getting "System function format-number#2 is not available with this host language/version".
Please suggest how to add xquery 3.0 version in xquery.

Below is the xquery code.

```
<Amt>{fn:format-number(//OutstandingBal, '0.000')}<Amt>
```

Comment: Try to use a Camel version that supports XQuery 3 based on a Saxon version that supports it. You can of course try whether a query prolog `xquery version '3.0';<Amt>{fn:format-number(//OutstandingBal, '0.000')}<Amt>` or `xquery version '3.1';<Amt>{fn:format-number(//OutstandingBal, '0.000')}<Amt>` changes some camel settings but I kind of doubt that, I would check which Camel version uses which Saxon version and try to use a version of Camel that allows the use of a recent enough Saxon version.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks for the information but it didn't work if query prolog with query version. I had tried with multiple camel-saxon versions but any of them didn't worked for me. Kindly help in saxon version which supports xquery 3.0

Comment: Saxon 9.8, I think, was the first Saxon version to implement the official XQuery 3.1 W3C recommendation. But I have no idea how to configure Camel or which Camel version to use to ensure Saxon 9.8 or later is used.